# What does usages mean in mvnrepository.com

Tags: maven, dependencies

While searching for maven dependencies on mvnrepository.com, it shows one column with usages. What does it mean?
i.e. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context when you click on this link it will show you different jars with version number and also it shows you one column called usages. Usages contains some numbers.

Comment: To be honest I have my doubts that the usage says something about the real usage of jar's cause mvnrepository can not access the download information from maven central..and other repositories so they can only be a number of search request which have been made on the page..nothing else...

Comment: It is not number of requests made on the page because if you click on [usages] link you will find projects and i think usages tracking the number of projects created from it (not downloads).

Comment: We have 15-20 modules which uses the third party jars (available on maven). We have maintain the list of all third party jars in single pom using dependency management. Now we want to generate similar report where we can see which module uses the jar from this pom. How we can generate such report ? Do we have any plugin for this ?

Answer (score 4):

If you click through the 'usages' button you see the projects that are also listed (i.e. in maven central) which have that project as a dependency. If you pick a project from the 'usages' to click into and then click on the most recent version and look at the 'dependencies' section then you find the project that you started from in that list somewhere. At least I suspect it's based on the dependencies of the most recent version but it could be that it's used in a/any version (haven't been able to determine that from my clicking around).

Answer (score 1):

Did you click on the number and see the information it shows you?

i think it means how many mvnrepository.com maven project dependenied it

Comment: The answer needs to be much higher quality

Comment: please give me a score,:)

Answer (score 0):

When I click on the library,
It appears to be **Used by (numeric) artifacts.**

So my guess is, to put it simply
I think it's the number of other libraries that used that library.

As the people above have already explained.